# how to let interstitial shown on every click pls correct my code

Tags: java, android, admob, interstitial

I don't know how to let ads shown on every click.
pls correct my code.

I try to put `varcounter = 1` not working
I don't know what to do
ads are shown randomly

```
 @Override
protected void onStart() {
    manageAd();
    super.onStart();
}

public void manageAd() {
    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("App Name", MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sp.edit();
    varCounter = sp.getInt("counter", 0);
    Log.e("VAR", "" + varCounter);
    if (varCounter == 0) {
        requestNewGoogleInterstitial();
        editor.putInt("counter", varCounter + 1);
    } else if (varCounter >= 2) {
        editor.putInt("counter", 0);
    } else {
        editor.putInt("counter", varCounter + 1);
    }
    editor.apply();
}
```